# jq returns "Invalid numeric literal" with --arg

Tags: jq

The command below is returning an error (jq version: 1.6):

```
$ jq --arg b bar . <<< '{ "foo": $b }'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

The [jq 1.6 manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) describes the `--arg` option thusly:

> - `--arg name value`:
>
> This option passes a
> value to the jq program as a predefined   variable. If you run jq with
> `--arg foo bar`, then `$foo` is   available in
> the program and has the value `"bar"`. Note that  
> `value` will be treated as a string, so `--arg foo
> 123` will   bind `$foo` to `"123"`.
>
> Named arguments are also available to the jq program as  
> `$ARGS.named`.

My usage appears correct. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My variable call was not within the jq program

The here-string I'm passing into `jq`

```
{ "foo": $b }
```

is **not** "the jq program" mentioned in the manual's `--arg` description. The lone `.` was the entire program, and did not use the variable `$b`.

I was trying to construct JSON from scratch by passing in my pattern on stdin. Instead, I should have provided the `--null-input` option, and replaced the `.` with the pattern I was attempting to pass in.

Description of `--null-input`

> - `--null-input`/`-n`:
>
> Don't read any input at all! Instead, the filter is run once  
> using `null` as the input. This is useful when using jq as
> a   simple calculator or to construct JSON data from scratch.

### Here's the correct invocation:

```
$ jq --arg b bar --null-input '{ "foo": $b }'
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```